# How to access images in downloaded unzipped folder?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

I am new to iOS and I have question, I am downloading resources ( additional images for app ) in iOS to folder

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* strDestPath = [NSString stringWithString:documentsDirPath];
```

only images and I put inside folder which is created by zipping .zip file ( same name ).
Is this right folder to hold resources for app and is there any way so I can treat all images inside this folder like one which I add to app before building ? ( I have to create table where every row contains one image from that unzipped folder ) ?
( I know to create table and cells when I have already images inside app, just this is confusing ).

Comment: implement lazy loading or if you keep images it will increase size of app every time

Comment: @johnykumar Hi, I have problem to find example how to load file, in this case it is formed like above inside soma_path/Documents/images, how to load one with name image_1.png ? I googled but all are for bundle when is inside project, this is downloaded from server.

Comment: ok get data of that file after document directory path add /images/image_1.png and using nsdata data read data from that file after that create image with nsdata.

Comment: before downloading show place holder after donloading add images in table cell and reload tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imgPath];
UIImage *thumbNail = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
```